# Вызов метода по завершении конструктора

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

Как можно вызвать метод `self.task()` не прибегая к костылю `QTimer.singleShot(0, self.task)`?
Если в `__init__` просто вызвать `self.task()` то `taskbarProgress` не будет показываться, т.к. `self.taskbarButton.setWindow(self.windowHandle())` надо вызывать вне конструктора.
Можно после `mainWindow.show()` дописать строку `mainWindow.task()`, но хотелось бы сделать это внутри класса, вне зависимости от внешнего кода, если так можно сказать.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, QWidget, QApplication):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.task)
        # self.task()

    def task(self):
        self.taskbarButton = QWinTaskbarButton(self)
        self.taskbarButton.setWindow(self.windowHandle())

        self.taskbarProgress = self.taskbarButton.progress()

        self.taskbarProgress.setRange(0, 100)
        self.taskbarProgress.setVisible(True)
        self.taskbarProgress.setValue(random.randint(0, 100))

        self.taskbarProgress.show()




if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Обновление**

> Зачем вам от трех классов наследоваться?

Спасибо за замечание, учту.

> Странно, что вне конструктора не вызывается.

Напротив, `self.taskbarButton.setWindow(self.windowHandle())` будет правильно работать если вызывать **вне** конструктора (в другом методе) (нашел эту информацию на англ. SO), решение - вынести в метод, и вызывать уже этот метод в конструкторе (судя по примерам док-ции Qt на С++ это работает), **но**, если в Питоне так делать (`# self.task()`) то всё равно `self.taskbarButton.setWindow(self.windowHandle())` не работает. (Немного запутанно объяснено, но не знаю как понятнее)

> переопределите тогда метод `show`

Если использовать `def showEvent(self, e)...`, то будет срабатывать каждый раз при разворачивании окна.

---

Попробовал сделать переопределением:

```
def show(self):
    self.setVisible(True)
    self.task()
```

Работает, но разве это сильно лучше, чем `QTimer.singleShot(0, self.task)`?

Comment: Странно, что вне конструктора не вызывается. `Можно после mainWindow.show() дописать строку mainWindow.task()` переопределите тогда метод `show` и в нем вызывает `task`.

Comment: Зачем вам от трех классов наследоваться? От `QApplication` вообще нет смысла, так же как и одновременно наследоваться от `QMainWindow, QWidget`, ведь `QMainWindow` сам наследуется от `QWidget`

Comment: Используйте тогда тот метод, который работает :)

Comment: Неа, это просто альтернатива. Лучше используйте `QTimer.singleShot(0, self.task)`